# JIRA Service Desk

Tags: jira

I'm implementing JIRA Service Desk in my organization and I have the following blocker:

I have 20 client companies which has their own users that are creating issues on my company's JIRA Service Desk e.g: Client A, Client B, Client C...

The users register on the JIRA Service Desk via Customer Portal (Help Center) e.g. user@clientA.com, user@clientB.com...

**Question:** how can I create a filter that shows all the issues posted from the users of each client company e.g.: All the issues from users registered with ...@clientA.com.

This issue is a real blocker for my company at the moment and I need your help.
Thank you in advance!

Best,
Iv

Answer (score 1):

you can use JQL to list issues with Jira Search API.

for example

```
project="ABCD" and reporter IN ("abc@clientb.com", "bbc@clientb.com")
```

ref - https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-search-get

Answer (score 0):

Sadly searching for issues from Jira level by user mail domain is impossible as it's specified in [THIS](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/187094/is-there-any-way-to-search-for-a-certain-email-address-domain) topic. But You can create new customfield that will be filled with email of user that created issue and it will be searchable with:
`~`

for example `YourNewCustomfield ~ domainThatYouNeed.com`

I'm not sure if You can place this email automatically but it's only solution for this. Eventually create new customfield that user will choose client name and search by it (if Your clients list is not a secret...).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Service Desk does not offer this type of functionality. Using the route below, you'll get ALL Service Desk issues. Then you'll need to loop through each issue and push to an array only your desired domains:

```
https://mywebsite.com/rest/servicedeskapi/request
```